# Drive size adjustment

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a RAW drive that Windows says is smaller than it is.
I could use the SD Card Formatter to do the size adjustment but it requires a quick format to do that.

Do you know of any other way to do a drive size adjustment without formatting (as I want to recover files from the RAW drive before formatting)?

Comment: You can try TestDisk (https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to try to get the files off the RAW drive before formatting.

Comment: Use a partition manager such as DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/, to access data in parts of the drive that do not appear in Windows, then use that tool to repartition the USB drive.

Comment: Can you give the two sizes?

Comment: I tried TestDisk didn't have size adjustment and DiskGenius size adjustment did not work, when I changed the 4gb to 64gb it changed to 0 by itself